# OTX alienvault | API | Get new pulses of the last 24h

Tags: malware-analysis

I would like to get the "pulses" of the last 24h from the [Alienvault OTX API](https://otx.alienvault.com/api), as a free user.

I tried using `/api/v1/pulses/subscribed` with the `modified_since:` parameter. As the name suggests this does not return new pulses, only modified pulses.

Has someone tried doing something similar? Or is using a different solution?

Answer (score 0):

The `modified_since` parameter takes a datetime value in the format `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:dd+TZ`. If you're pulling the data using a script, have it check for the current time and decrease the time by 24 hours and use that timestamp for pulling the data from Alienvault.

I was able to request this endpoint, `/api/v1/pulses/subscribed?modified_since=2023-05-15T00:00:00+00:00"`, which provide me with 15 results

Alternatively you can use the Python SDK which might be a better route for automation. Hope this helps!